# php exec function execute php script via browser different from not via browser

Tags: php, exec

I have a PHP script called **a.php** that calls `exec()` to execute php command to send data to another platform, and then get data from it. i have found much information. i still failed according to their ways.

**a.php** uses curl to send data and use `json_decode()` to parse data from `curl_exec()` function.

My environment:

- php 5.3.2

  - php.ini

    - safe_mode = Off
    - disable_functions=
- server: apache
- os: linux

in my php class:

I use `exec("php a.php > /data0/log/log.log")`, then I access it via browser, but i get nothing.

Finally I find that I can use php exec to execute php script, because I find data in the platform where I send data. However **a.php** shows nothing. i also find nothing in `/data0/log/log.log`, but if i use `php a.php > /data0/log/log.log` in linux, then I can find information which i use '`echo`, `print_r`' in **a.php**, so I think **a.php** is correct.

I use `exec("php -cli a.php > /data0/log/log.log &")`, i got undefined function `json_decode()` in `/data0/log/log.log`.

I don't know how to fix this problem. But in my another server it can execute successfully. I only use `exec("php a.php")`.

thanks 
van

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve the problem. 
The detail is that php has two versions in linux.
So I only assign the path of php.